How to import utility functions from a python package in DLT pipeline?
I am trying to import python utility functions from a python package in my DLT notebook but getting this error:
NameError: name 'CommonUtils' is not defined,None,Map(),Map(),List(),List(),Map())
My folder structure is as follows:
structured/
├── dlt_notebook
├── intermediate_notebook
└── common_utils/
    ├── __init__.py
    └── CommonUtils.py

CommonUtils.py has all the functions defined in it.
init.py has this import only : from common_utils.CommonUtils import *
When I do this import in intermediate_notebook, it works fine. I can create UDFs and use them.
But incase of DLT, I get the above mentioned error.
Can anyone please guide, what I am doing wrong?
